# How to placed the GridPanel and Panel at the same level?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I want to place the panel and the grid panel at the same level.

```
.------------------------------------------------.
:                    Ext.Panel                   :
: .--------------------.  .--------------------. :
: :                    :  :                    : :
: :     Ext.Panel      :  : Ext.grid.GridPanel : :
: :                    :  :                    : :
: .--------------------.  .--------------------. :
.------------------------------------------------.
```

But the grid panel is collapsed when I used `layout: 'border'`.
When I used `layout: 'auto'` panels were placed at the different levels.

```
var filter_panel = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'filter_panel',
    title: 'Filter',
    region: 'west'
});

var result_panel = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    id: 'result_panel',
    title: 'Result',
    region: 'center',
    colModel: columns
});

var main_panel = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'main_panel',
    layout: 'border',
    items : [filter_panel, result_panel],
    renderTo: render_extjs
});
```

**======= UPD =======**

Only this is solved problem :(

```
#main_panel .x-box-inner {
  display: flex;  
}

#result_panel {
  flex: 1;
  position: static;
  margin: 5px;
}

#result_panel .x-panel-header-text:after {
  content: "Result";
}

#filter_panel {
  flex: 1;
  position: static;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var filter_panel = new Ext.Panel({
        title: 'Filter',
                flex:1
    });

    var result_panel = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        title: 'Result',
        colModel: columns,
                flex:1
    });

    var main_panel = new Ext.Panel({
        layout: {
            type:'hbox'
        },
        items : [filter_panel, result_panel]
    })
```

Here is a fiddle to show you how it works https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1jbl

Comment: Nice one, you won ;)

Comment: why you used vbox?

Comment: Typed too fast :/

Comment: You are create 2 simple panels :) Without grid panel